# Change default position on bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I'm using this bootstrap datetimepicker: 
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

How can I change default position of calendar widget in jQuery?

```
$(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker').each(function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
      locale: 'pl',
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
      defaultDate: moment(),
    });
  });
});
```

I want to open calendar widget always under input and i don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [widgetpositioning](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning) option:

For example:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
  widgetPositioning: {
    horizontal: 'left',
    vertical: 'bottom'
  }
});
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/44ds5tg7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `widgetPositioning` parameter

The options vertical are `"top"`, `"bottom"`, or `"auto"`.

Its meaning:

```
widgetPositioning: {
    horizontal: 'left',
    vertical: 'bottom'
}
```

So the entire implementation can be:

```
var tdpOption = {
    /** your parameters here */
    locale: 'pl', // or your location
   
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm",
    date: moment().hour(1).minute(0).second(0),
    defaultDate: moment(),
    widgetPositioning:{
        vertical: 'bottom',//"top", "bottom" or "auto"
    },
}

$(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker').each(function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker(tdpOption);
  });
});
```